# ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom wh object What is happening?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am using code suggestion written at angular Fire documentation, but the console browser return this error:

**ERROR FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom wh object**

What is happening?

That's my code:

```
export class CategoryComponent {

  private fs: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
  categories$: Observable<Category[]>;

  constructor() {
    // get a reference to the user-profile collection
    const categoryCollection = collection(this.fs, 'categories');

    // get documents (data) from the collection using collectionData
    this.categories$ = collectionData(categoryCollection) as Observable<Category[]>;

    console.log(categoryCollection);
  }

}
```

That's my HTML file:

```
<section>
  <h1>Categories</h1>
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of categories$ |async">
          {{item.category}}
          {{item.log}}
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: error: mismatch between the object type that Firebase expects and the object type you are providing. check your category model and the database structure. to debug change the <Category> to <any>   in any case consider using angular/fire it designed to work with firebase in angular

Comment: I changed <Category> by <any> and this error doesn't appear....  But the html doesn't  render the items in the screen, and console doesn't print the Category Collection

Comment: The any was just to make sure that there is a mismatch between category model and your dadabase structure. Share your models

Answer (score 0):

Argument for `collectionData` should be `Query`.

```
    // get a reference to the user-profile collection
    const categoryCollection = collection(this.fs, 'categories');
    const q = query(categoryCollection);

    // get documents (data) from the collection using collectionData
    this.categories$ = collectionData(q) as Observable<Category[]>;
```

Comment: I got the same issue still does not work with your approach

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this particular problem.

If you're using Angular 16, it may be helpful to you to upgrade AngularFire to 16.0.0, the latest version as of late October, 2023. From this version onward, AngularFire will share major versioning numbers with Angular itself.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/releases/tag/16.0.0

After I edited my `package.json`, deleted `node_modules`, issued `npm install`, and restarted my application (`ng serve`) the error disappeared.